# Is it possible to skip over a subdirectory when performing an operation over an entire directory?

Tags: batch-file, move, skip

So I have this code for sorting files within a complex of subdirectories within a main directory:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET relroot=g:\Pictures\Uda 18
(SET relroot=g:\Pictures\Uda 18)
SET "relroot=g:\Pictures\Uda 18"

SET "destdir=g:\Pictures\Uda 18\Sets"

:again
(SET artist=)
SET /p artist="Artist? "

IF NOT DEFINED artist GOTO :eof

MD "%destdir%\%artist%" 2>nul

FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 
   ' dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*%artist%*" '
   ) DO (
>>undo.txt ECHO %%i^|%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi
MOVE "%%i" "%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi" >nul)
)

GOTO again
```

It takes an input, searches the directory 'Uda 18' and everything within it, and moves all files with the input in their names to a folder named after the input under the directory 'Uda 18/Sets'. However, careless testing has caused me to draw files from 'Uda 18/Sets', the names of which mean they can't be reorganised using the batch. To avoid this, I need to exclude 'Uda 18/Sets' from where files are taken from, but I can't find a way. So as the titles asks; is it possible to skip a select subdirectory, and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to draw the file names except those from the "sets" folder:

```
dir /b /s /a-d "uda 18" | find /v /i "sets"
```

... and with your folders:

```
echo "%destdir%\%artist%" | find /v /i "sets" >nul && goto:createFolder || goto:eof
```

Comment: That didn't work; the folder was created but no files were touched and the window then closed on its own.

Comment: This doesn't create any folder. It displays all files in "uda 18"'s subfolders, except files in "Sets".

Comment: Not this part alone, but in place amongst the rest of the batch, the folder that would normally be made was made but the files weren't processed.

Comment: OK, now I know, what you men (hopefully :)) & enhanced my answer.

Answer (score 0):

personally, I would prefer creatíng a destination-directory BESIDES the source-directory, not within:

```
source:        g:\pictures\uda 18\xxx
destination:   g:\pictures\sorted\uda 18\xxx
```

This way you do not only avoid that problem, you will also allways have a clear and consistent directory-structure

Comment: I want to be able to sort without change the way I arrange my folders.

Answer (score 0):

I too would separate my destination folder from the folders to be processed.

Moving it out and moving it back later is an option though.

```
move "g:\Pictures\Uda 18\Sets" "g:\Pictures"
do your other commands here
move  "g:\Pictures\Sets" "g:\Pictures\Uda 18"
```

Comment: I suppose that's a possibility, but for certain reasons I find my preference laying in keeping the folder structure as it is through the whole process.

Comment: Does the SETS folder have any subfolders?  Are there any other folders possible with the name sets in the folder tree?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ( 
   ' dir /s /b /a-d "%relroot%\*%artist%*" ^|findstr /v /i /b /c:"%destdir%\\"'
   ) DO ( ECHO MOVE "%%i" "%destdir%\%artist%\%%~nxi")
```

Should list the MOVE to be performed `/v` EXCLUDING any directory `/b` beginning `/i` case-insensitive `/c:` the entire string including spaces ... where `\` escapes `\` so therefore excluding "g:\Pictures\Uda 18\Sets" and any of its subdirectories (where the full filename would begin `g:\Pictures\Uda 18\Sets\"`

simply remove the `/v` to select `ONLY` the matching files in `"g:\Pictures\Uda 18\Sets"` and its subdirectories.

Comment: The problem here is that findstr.exe is located in my C:\ drive, and the batch + folders being organised are all on my G:\ drive. I would have to redirect it all to the location of my findstr.exe, but that would result in the batch trying to do everything within there as opposed to the directories specified (and did, upon testing). Placing the findstr.exe on my G:\ drive did not remedy the situation either.

Comment: findstr.exe should be in `c:\windows\system32` and another version in `c:\windows\syswow64` (if you are running 64-bit.) Wherever it is, your PATH (which is a semicolon-separated list of directories) should include that directory. The `path` is the list of directories that Windows looks through (in order) to find any executable that isn't in the current directory. `findstr` is working on a `"file"` (the output of the `dir` command) that exists only in memory.